# Vectorize a triangle scan line in MATLAB/Octave

Tags: matlab, graphics, octave, vectorization, rasterizing

I am new to Octave/MATLAB. I want to vectorize a simple scan-line fill for a triangle. Here is the while loop I want to eliminate:

```
 #Iterate over all the scan lines from bottom to top
 while(yCurr <= 200)

    #VARIABLES: 
    #  img - Zero matrix used as an image. Zero is black. Assume 320x200 pixels.
    #  leftIdx - Vector that contains the left-most pixel to fill in each
    #      scanline. Dim is 1x200. Each element represents x-coord of a pixel.
    #  rightIdx - Vector that contains the right-most pixel to fill in each
    #      scanline. Dim is also 1x200. Each element represents x-coord of a pixel.
    #  yCurr - The current row being scanned.    

    #Fill all the pixels in one scan line 
    img(leftIdx(yCurr) : rightIdx(yCurr), yCurr) = color;

    #Increment the row
    yCurr++;

 endwhile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution - you can change your loop directly to one arrayfun call. arrayfun is a fancy way of writing a loop - it calls user-defined function for all supplied parameters. The caveat is that anonymous functions that one usually uses with arrayfun can not assign variables. But, you can write a normal function that assigns color to img and pass it to arrayfun as parameter:

```
 function doAllWork(img, rightIdx, leftIdx)

 arrayfun(@fill, 1:size(img, 1));

    function fill(i)
      img(leftIdx(i):rightIdx(i), i) = color;
    end
 end
```

I have defined the fill function as a local function in doAllWork so that it has access to img, leftIdx, rightIdx.

**Complicated solution** Usually in such cases, to do an assignment in one go you want to use sub2ind to get a linear index into the matrix (in short, in C you would write sth. like j*nx+i). You then write img(ind) instead of img(indrow, indcol). The problem is that every row has a different number of non-zeros in different places.

The (complicated) idea is to create an explicit column index array Ii{row} = [leftIdx(row):rightIdx(row)] and corresponding row index array Ij{row} = [row*ones(1, lenght(Ii{row}))] for all rows. Without a loop that can be done using arrayfun. Once you have this, you can construct a linear index into your img using sub2ind on coresponding Ii/Ij entries, also called using arrayfun. The code looks like this

```
nrows=1:size(img, 1);
Ii=arrayfun(@(i)(leftIdx(i):rightIdx(i)), nrows, 'UniformOutput', false);
Ij=arrayfun(@(i)(i*ones(1,length(Ii{i}))), nrows, 'UniformOutput', false);
lin=arrayfun(@(i)(sub2ind(size(A), Ij{i}, Ii{i})), nrows, 'UniformOutput', false);
img([lin{:}])=color;
```

This approach is not of much use in your case - it is way too complicated. But it is instructive in what arrayfun can do, and the trick with sub2ind is generally very useful.

Comment: Thank your for the answer. I grok with simple solution and had considered using arrayfun. I admit I do not understand yet the complex solution yet, but I will look into sub2ind as it shows up frequently in "hints and tips" sections. The solution allows me to avoid the loop, but I have a hidden agenda of parallelizing the code. I wonder if Octave is smart enough to divide the arrayfun work over multiple cores? Answer voted up.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your original loop-based solution is the best solution.
Why?

1. Because until you haven't done profiling you cannot know whether a vectorized solution is actually faster.
2. Because your code that uses for loop is clear for the reader!  It contains only 4 lines of code and one can understand its purpose merely by taking a look.

The only thing that I would change is `while`->`for`

```
for yCurr = 1:200
    img(leftIdx(yCurr) : rightIdx(yCurr), yCurr) = color;
 end
```

Comment: Well said. I do not know if the loop is a performance bottleneck. Performance is not my first concern. I want to learn the MATLAB programming paradigm and I have the sense that often loops can be turned into matrix ops. But not always. :-).  I am up-voting this answer for its enlightened software engineering practices.

Answer (score 1):

*Although not the OPs main question (i.e. how to vectorize the raster scan)*, a clean looking solution in MATLAB for filling in values in a triangle can come from using `poly2mask` to specify the area inside the triangle, using the triangle vertices, and use logical indexing to assign values.

```
% Example values
yCurr = 1:200;
img = zeros(320, 200);
leftIdx = ones(1,200);
rightIdx = 1:200;
color = 1;

% Define polygon vertices and get mask
x = [leftIdx(1) leftIdx(200) rightIdx(1) rightIdx(200)];
y = [1 1 200 200];
bw = poly2mask(x,y,320,200);
% Assign color values
img(bw) = color;
```

Since `poly2mask` most probably uses some underlying `for,` it is not a vectorized version of a rasterizing scan. However, it offers the benefit of handling more complex polygonal areas.

Comment: Great call. I did not know about poly2mask. I am selecting the answer that spoke to vectorization, but I have decided to dump my own scan line function and use poly2mask. I am up-voting your answer. Thanks.